# Is it possible to preform SFTP functions from Argo workflows?

Tags: kubernetes, sftp, argo-workflows, argo

I have a KON application that is deployed with and ARGO Workflow in the same cluster. I want to SFTP a file, that gets created by the application, from the cluster server over to an on premise server I have.

I know SFTP can be used as an event source but I haven't been able to setup SFTP from an argo workflow to an on premise server. Part of the issue is I do not see the folder where the files that the application creates go to.